# appdelegate dealloc will be called only once?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

If we release any allocated variable in dealloc of Appdelegate method, I allocate the same in the same appdelegate.m
file, will the dealloc handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will handle it every time when will called dealloc. Generally only once.